# How can I set jmeter results to nanoseconds?

Tags: jmeter

I can't seem to set results time to nanoseconds.

Uncommenting `sampleresult.useNanoTime=true` does nothing.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Have you configured this property `sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000`

Answer (score 0):

As per current version ([JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32)) it is not possible.

If you look into [SampleResult.getTime() function JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getTime--):

> **getTime**
>
> *public long getTime()*
>
> Get the time it took this sample to occur.
>
> **Returns**:
> elapsed time in **milliseonds**

So millisecond precision is the maximum you can get from JMeter test results as of now.

Comment: now there is jmeter version 5.x, is it still not possible ?